# Moq, SetupGet, Mocking a property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties, moq

I'm trying to mock a class, called `UserInputEntity`, which contains a property called `ColumnNames`: (it does contain other properties, I've just simplified it for the question)

```
namespace CsvImporter.Entity
{
    public interface IUserInputEntity
    {
        List<String> ColumnNames { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserInputEntity : IUserInputEntity
    {
        public UserInputEntity(List<String> columnNameInputs)
        {
            ColumnNames = columnNameInputs;
        }

        public List<String> ColumnNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a presenter class:

```
namespace CsvImporter.UserInterface
{
    public interface IMainPresenterHelper
    {
        //...
    }

    public class MainPresenterHelper:IMainPresenterHelper
    {
        //....
    }

    public class MainPresenter
    {
        UserInputEntity inputs;

        IFileDialog _dialog;
        IMainForm _view;
        IMainPresenterHelper _helper;

        public MainPresenter(IMainForm view, IFileDialog dialog, IMainPresenterHelper helper)
        {
            _view = view;
            _dialog = dialog;
            _helper = helper;
            view.ComposeCollectionOfControls += ComposeCollectionOfControls;
            view.SelectCsvFilePath += SelectCsvFilePath;
            view.SelectErrorLogFilePath += SelectErrorLogFilePath;
            view.DataVerification += DataVerification;
        }


        public bool testMethod(IUserInputEntity input)
        {
            if (inputs.ColumnNames[0] == "testing")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried the following test, where I mock the entity, try to get `ColumnNames` property to return a initialized `List<string>()` but it's not working:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod_ReturnsTrue()
    {
        Mock<IMainForm> view = new Mock<IMainForm>();
        Mock<IFileDialog> dialog = new Mock<IFileDialog>();
        Mock<IMainPresenterHelper> helper = new Mock<IMainPresenterHelper>();

        MainPresenter presenter = new MainPresenter(view.Object, dialog.Object, helper.Object);

        List<String> temp = new List<string>();
        temp.Add("testing");

        Mock<IUserInputEntity> input = new Mock<IUserInputEntity>();

    //Errors occur on the below line.
        input.SetupGet(x => x.ColumnNames).Returns(temp[0]);

        bool testing = presenter.testMethod(input.Object);
        Assert.AreEqual(testing, true);
    }
```

The errors I get state that there are some invalid arguments + Argument 1 cannot be converted from string to

```
System.Func<System.Collection.Generic.List<string>>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

`ColumnNames` is a property of type `List<String>` so when you are setting up you need to pass a `List<String>` in the `Returns` call as an argument (or a func which return a `List<String>`)

But with this line you are trying to return just a `string`

```
input.SetupGet(x => x.ColumnNames).Returns(temp[0]);
```

which is causing the exception.

Change it to return whole list:

```
input.SetupGet(x => x.ColumnNames).Returns(temp);
```

Answer (score 13):

Mocking read-only properties means properties with getter method only.

**Note** that you should declare it as `virtual`, otherwise `System.NotSupportedException` will be thrown.

If you're using an interface, that does not apply to you. It works instantly because the mock framework will implement the interface on the fly for you.

Comment: So how does one declare a read-only property as virtual in an interface?

Comment: @erict you don't need to specify virtual if you are using an interface, because interface methods are by default virtual

Comment: It bothers me to make a property virtual only for testability. You should be able to read code and gain insight into the design. Having to guess if something is virtual for testability or not is annoying.